# Soft Keyboard Disappearing when changing input

Tags: c#, uwp, keyboard

Strange problem here which was caused by the most recent win 10 update 1709

I have a uwp app that is installed on a tablet which has assigned access setup. So it is locked to this application in tablet mode. This was all fine until the last update which broke the keyboard.

It pops up the first time, then when tapping the next input box it disappears. Then to get it to return you need to tap in the box again.

I'm using the input scope on a few of them, and this seems to work intermittently too.

Here's a video to demonstrate what I mean:
https://youtu.be/c_CtqFLFUdY

Any ideas? All nuget packages are up to date and it's targeting the latest version, I'm at a loss!

Comment: If your app doesn't run in assigned access mode, will you face this issue?

Comment: I don't think so, but I haven't actually tried that. It needs to be in assigned access as it's used in a public location

Comment: Please try to test your app without assigned access mode on your developing machine. Because we need to do troubleshooting.